# using pipe with bundle show and gnome-open

Tags: command-line, nautilus, pipe

(I asked [an almost identical question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11582414) with no response. Am hoping that  ask ubuntu is a better spot for this and so am re-asking here.)

I haven't used pipe much and am wondering if I'm doing something wrong. If I run:

```
bundle show jquery-rails
```

I get the following:

```
/home/u1104/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/jquery-rails-2.0.0
```

And if I run:

```
gnome-open /home/u1104/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/bootstrap-sass-2.0.0
```

Nautilus opens to the correct location. So I want to save myself the trouble of copying and pasting the results of one command into the other and I thought this was what the pipe was for... but when I run the following:

```
bundle show jquery-rails | gnome-open
```

I get the following error:

```
Usage: gnome-open <url>
/home/u1104/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/shell/basic.rb:63:in `flush': Broken pipe (Errno::EPIPE)
    from /home/u1104/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/shell/basic.rb:63:in `say'
...
```

Is there a way to get the results of my `bundle show` to automatically open in nautilus?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to pass the output of the `bundle` command as an *argument* to `gnome-open`, not as *input* to it. Try this instead:

```
gnome-open $(bundle show jquery-rails)
```